# Crash during Core Data Model migration

Tags: core-data, crash, migration

I'm getting this crash log when I create a new version of my Core Data Model and then restart the app:

> *** -[NSRelationshipDescription name]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1d032e240

It seems the model migration doesn't work whereas I'm using the `NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption` and `NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption` store options...

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: the changes I've made to my model are just the addition of a new attribute (Boolean as NSNumber) to en existant entity

**EDIT**: here is the Core Data initialization code:

```
- (BOOL) loadCatalog
{
    // Unload any existing store
    [self _unloadCurrentStore];

    // Create a new managed object context
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    _managedObjectContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy;
    _managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

    // Create the persistent store
    NSURL *storeURL = [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate].catalogDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Store.sqlite"];
    NSDictionary *storeOptions = @{ NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                                    NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES };
    return ([_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:storeOptions error:nil] != nil);
}
```

Comment: Those options aren't always enough for model migration. What kind of changes did you make?

Comment: I just added an attribute to an entity

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer then. This is not a typical error that someone would encounter as part of model migration. If you edit your question to provide a lot more detail about what exactly your code is doing, someone may be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I edited my question with the part of code which seems to fail.. Not sure it will help you :( That's strange because that's the first time that happens, before I had no migration issues